# Kubuntu - Missing Menu Entries after installation

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10

I just installed Kubuntu 14.10 new, because of some issues with it before. And I installed some software like Thunderbird, Google Chrome and Skype. But none of the Software is listed in the menu. Even search won't show it. I installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ...
```

Just like I always do. But it is nothing in the menu. I can start the Applications from the terminal, so they are definitely installed.

What can I do to find the Applications through the menu? Do I need to change settings, or is it a new "feature" that new installed applications won't show in the menu?
I hope someone can help.

**Edit:**
Errormessage I got for `kbuildsycoca4 --noincremental`

```
kbuildsycoca4 running...
kbuildsycoca4(2821) VFolderMenu::loadDoc: Parse error in  "/home/svenja/.config/menus/applications-merged/xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu" , line  1 , col  1 :  "unexpected end of file"
```

Comment: ...and if you move/(remove) the xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu ? Can the kbuildsycoca4 add the missing items to the KDE menu ?

Comment: Are there more files in the ~/.config/menus/ ?

Comment: In my experience:  `line  1 , col  1 :  "unexpected end of file"` happens when the menu file in the error message is empty.  Removing the empty file gets rid of `kbuildsycoca4` error.

Answer (score 1):

**At here**

Installing the Thunderbird:

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

After the installation is done the KDE Menu is updated.

[image]

The Thunderbird can be find from the 'Recently Installed ', 'Internet' and through the 'Search' bar.

**Something to try**

```
:~$ kbuildsycoca4 --help
Usage: kbuildsycoca4 [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] 

Rebuilds the system configuration cache.

Generic options:
  --help                    Show help about options
  --help-qt                 Show Qt specific options
  --help-kde                Show KDE specific options
  --help-all                Show all options
  --author                  Show author information
  -v, --version             Show version information
  --license                 Show license information
  --                        End of options

Options:
  --nosignal                Do not signal applications to update
  --noincremental           Disable incremental update, re-read everything
  --checkstamps             Check file timestamps
  --nocheckfiles            Disable checking files (dangerous)
  --global                  Create global database
  --menutest                Perform menu generation test run only
  --track <menu-id>         Track menu id for debug purposes
```

Try to rebuild the system configuration cache with the 'noincremental' option.

```
kbuildsycoca4 --noincremental
```

Any error messages ?

**----EDIT----**

The xdg-desktop-menu-dummy.menu is made by the xdg-desktop-menu

```
man xdg-desktop-menu

NAME
       xdg-desktop-menu - command line tool for (un)installing desktop menu items
```

At here it doesn't prevent the KDE menu update.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer. I get an error meassage about "unexpected end of the file". I copied the full message to the question itself.